# P4 labels view field

Tags: c#, perforce

I am trying to get a list of labels from perforce.

I run the command "p4 labels -e Project_*".

It actually works, and I have access to several fields, but I don't seem to be able to get the "view" field of the label.

Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p4 labels` will give you the list of labels, but to get the description of the label itself, you want `p4 label -o labelname`.

Comment: Great! I tried the p4 label before, but not with the -o option. I tried it and it works. Thanks!